# What is a decent way to prevent a malicious user from guessing the UserID of another User using ASP.NET, Entity Framework & SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm looking for a way to make it difficult for a malicious logged in User to guess the User ID of another user to try and get/change information for another user.

Currently I've got IdentityUsers that each have a NormalUser with more information attached. To create/edit/delete users you'll often see [url]/[action]/[NormalUserID] in the Address bar. Currently the UserID is an automatically incrementing integer and i'm contemplating of changing it to a GUID.

Of course i check whether or not the user has rights to change or view this person (via roles) but it is possible to have users on the same roles so those kind of need to be checked manually. I think this would at least slow down any kind of automated guessing on the malicious user part.

Are there better ways to do it? Is there already something that can help me out with this?

Comment: There always needs to be blocks to stop users from accessing information they shouldn’t. Making something harder to guess is not worth it. Sooner or later it will fail.

Comment: Is your business rule that a user can only ever edit his/her self?  are they allowed to view other users?

Comment: If userid <> current user, don't let them access it. If admins need to edit other users, make a table with a list of "who reports to who" or whatever layer you need to prevent any basic user from accessing other records.

Comment: I guessed as much, which is why i added that I already check whether the user has rights to change or view a person. But since this needs to happen manually with overlapping roles, the possibility of it going wrong and forgetting to add these blocks or wrongly implementing them is non-zero. Obscuring user information with hard to guess GUIDs for example seems like a decent roadblock, which is why i asked for advice on that specifically.

Comment: Maybe you should look into a whole different approach. Use the session instead of query strings to pass around data like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking user permissions is the best thing to do anyway. If you wish additionally to prevent potential hacker from guessing user ID of other users, you may use GUID as your user ID.

Comment: I've seen some really old posts that cautioned against using GUID as a primary key. I'm guessing it would it be fine however to keep the incrementing int UserID as the primary key and just add a GUID column for front-end work?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Just make sure to add index in database to the GUID, so the lookup would be fast.

Comment: A GUID as a primary key is fine. But it is NOT fine as the clustered index. That is almost certainly what those other posts are referring to.